# Booking payments using wallet and wallet topup using paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on hotel booking where user can book
a room using prepaid credits store in a wallet. User can topup or reload wallet via paypal. 
Currently i have the following models.

Room ( rate, no, capacity)
Booking ( booking_no, room_id, status, amount)
Wallet( user_id, balance)
WalletTransaction( wallet_id, amount, type (Payment,Topup))
TopUp(wallet_id, amount, status (pending_paypal_payment, success))
Payment( booking_id, amount, status( completed, refunded)

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions I might make are to use more conventional names and verbose naming on your database fields.

I would think it better to use `credit` or `debit` as  for your wallet, but also do you even need a field name for that?  Standard is that `debit` is a negative number and `credit` is a positive number.  It looks like `TopUp` and `Payment` do not need to be separate models because they share many of the same fields. It's not "wrong" per say, but seems irregular.

You might want to name `Transaction` instead of `WalletTransaction` unless there are other types of transactions, but then you might use polymorphic relation.

For field names, I would be more verbose and use `number` instead of `no`.
Do you need `booking_no` ? I would expect that to be the primary key just `id` which would get incrementally assigned when you add a new booking record.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you give your sample models for this ?